# What does ty mean in type stmt_ty in CPython?

Tags: cpython

I saw some there are some typedef in CPython as shown below, what does ty mean in the type name? A short form of type?

```
typedef struct _mod *mod_ty;
typedef struct _stmt *stmt_ty;
typedef struct _expr *expr_ty;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that it's a `typedef` and the new type is simply the structure name with `_ty` appended, I think you've hit the nail on the head.

It's just a short form of `type` so that you can instantly tell that a variable of type `xyzzy_ty` is simply a pointer to a variable of type `struct _xyyzy`.

The rules you follow for this sort of thing aren't set in stone but it's useful to be consistent.

[PEP7](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0007/) is the style guideline for CPython C source code, similar to [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the Python source code.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't seen such short form before. As it is a pointer, the most common short form would be p_mod.  Is there any document for the naming convention in CPython?